# SQL PHP | Same code is NOT working

Tags: php, sql-server, command

Edited!

This code works when I execute it on SQL Server Management, but when I tried to use it on my php code it failed. I don't find the source of the problem. How should i solve the problem?

I don't get any error message from PHP!

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_corps] (value, status_id)
VALUES ('blablabla', (SELECT id FROM [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_status] WHERE value='Active'))
```

PHP Code:

```
$corp = $_POST['corp'];
$userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_corps] (value, status_id)";
$userquery .= " VALUES ('$corp', (SELECT id FROM [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_status] WHERE value='Active'))";
$userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It's not the same code. Check again, there's a stray quote at the end

Comment: EDITED

I don't get any error message from php :/ We are looking the code , and try to find solution for two hour

Comment: Dangerous INSERT... That SELECT id FROM [gyakornok]... may return more than one row.

Comment: add init_set('error_reporting',1); on the top! , check the errror message

Answer (score 1):

Your sql code in php is NOT the same...

Here is the same:

```
$userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_corps] (value, status_id)";
$userquery .= " VALUES ('$corp', (SELECT id FROM [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_status] WHERE value='Active'))";
$userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);
```

without ' around SELECT

Comment: Display data base error:   `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` - add it after `sqlsrv_query`